# Mouse skipping with Ubuntu 18.04 on Dell Inspiron 3558

Tags: 18.04, mouse, dell

I am experiencing an intermittent problem of mouse skipping with my Dell Inspiron 3558 running Ubuntu 18.04.2. I sometimes have to reboot a couple of times before it stops skipping. I experience the issue with both wired and wireless mice. I even disabled the touchpad, which helped a little, but the problem persists. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

After exhausting various resources, I decided to try a different flavor of Linux. I installed LinuxMint 19.1 (Tessa). OMG, what a huge difference. I have been running it daily for over a week now. Not only did it solve my mouse skipping issue, the laptop now runs sooo much faster. I hope this info is helpful to others.